# Thymeleaf th:include doesn't work after update to Spring Boot 1.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an [application](https://github.com/opensource21/sze) which works fine with Spring Boot 1.2.6. Now I tried to 1.3.5 and have the problem, that the following statement doesn't work anymore:

```
<head >
    <title th:text="#{app.title} + ' - ' + #{login.title}"></title>
    <th:block th:include="main::head"/>
</head>
```

I can see in the Thymeleaf log that the `main.html` is found. Furthermore the Thymeleaf-Expressions from the `head` are evaluated. How ever the html in the browser has no content in head, neither title nor the content from [main.html](https://github.com/opensource21/sze/blob/15ad6f57147711737a202ac2f15af9f1ec4db79a/src/main/resources/templates/main.html).
As far as I can see the [Thymeleaf version](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blame/master/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L170) hasn't changed. 
So what can be the reason?

Comment: Check the class path for JARs with different versions of Thymeleaf. Also I suggest to enable debug messages and may be they will show something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the Layout dialect has changed. So I added the property `<thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>1.2.9</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>` to my pom.xml and everything was fine.

I created an [issue](https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/issues/114) for that.